# Change a list separator delimiter to another (python)

Tags: python, list, delimiter

I need help using Python.
Supposing I have the list [22,23,45].
Is it possible to get an output like this: [22;23:45] ?

Comment: Can the input have more than 3 elements? How does the output look then. Can you add more input -> output examples

Comment: Hi! What does that list represent? Where are you outputting to? Do you just want to print the list? Like print("[22;23:45]")?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the delimiters if you display your list as a string. You can then use the `join` method. The following example will display your list with `;` as a delimiter:

```
print(";".join(my_list))
```

This will only work if your list's items are string, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have more than one item

```
str(your_list[:1][0])+";" + ":".join(map(str,your_list[1:])) #'22;23:45'
```

Not sure why you want to wrap in the list but if you do just wrap around the above string in `list()`

Answer (score 0):

my list which was [22,23,45] returned [;2;2;,; ;2;3;,; ;4;5;,] for both methods.

To bring more information, I have a variable:

```
ID= [elements['id'] for elements in country]
```

Using a `print (ID)`, I get [22,23,45] so I suppose that the list is already to this form. 
Problem is: I need another delimiters because [22,23,45] corresponds to ['EU, UK', 'EU, Italy', 'USA, California'].

The output I wish is [22,23,45] --> ['EU, UK'; 'EU, Italy'; 'USA, California']

I don't know if it's clearer but hope it could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this I don't know exactly what do You want?

first solution:

```
list = [22,23,45]

str = ""
for i in list:
    str += "{}{}".format(i, ";")
new_list=str[:-len(";")]
print(new_list)
```

and this is second solution

```
list = [22,23,45]
print(list)
list=str(list)
list=list.split(",")
list=";".join(list)
print(list)
```

Comment: Can't vote for your solution because I'm new, but THANK YOU, it works !!

EDIT: Sorry, it did work for the numbers, but not for the corresponding list.
Using this solution on the second list give me the result below:
['EU, UK', 'EU, Italy', 'USA, California'] --> ['EU; UK'; 'EU; Italy'; 'USA; California']

I what I want for this one is:
['EU, UK', 'EU, Italy', 'USA, California'] --> ['EU, UK'; 'EU, Italy'; 'USA, California']