# How can I create a list with : separator?

Tags: list, separator

I created a list of integer numbered with this function:

```
def collect_ints():
    """It returns the list of numbers entered by the user"""

    ints = list()
    keep_asking = True
    while keep_asking:
        n = input()
        if n == "*":
            keep_asking = False
        if keep_asking:
            ints.append(int(n))
    return ints
```

However, in this way, I get a list of integers (on which I have to do some operations) with a comma (,) separator. How can I get the same list but with a `:` separator?

Comment: see:  [Change a list separator delimiter to another (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894699/change-a-list-separator-delimiter-to-another-python). Or, if you are not using python, please correct the tags in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return exactly as a list data type it is not possible in python. But you can make it seem like a list using string formatting

```
def collect_ints():
    ints = list()
    keep_asking = True
    while keep_asking:
        n = input()
        if n == "*":
            keep_asking = False
        if keep_asking:
            ints.append(int(n))
        output = "["
        for i in ints:
            output += "{}{}".format(i, ":")
        output = output[:-1] + "]"
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

The commas are used for visualizing lists. Lists do not have them, the print statement just prints them. So it is not possible to change them to other characters by default. But if you want to print them as a string with ':' as a delimiter, using 'replace' would be the best in my opinion.

```
def collect_ints():
    """It returns the list of numbers entered by the user"""

    ints = list()
    keep_asking = True
    while keep_asking:
        n = input()
        if n == "*":
            keep_asking = False
        if keep_asking:
            ints.append(int(n))
    return str(ints).replace(',', ':')
```